# Bouncing Card Algorithm

Tags: animation

What's a good algorithm for "bouncing cards" like the ones you see in solitaire games?

What's the coolest card animation you've seen?

**Edit** - Any besides the Windows game?

Answer (score 5):

The x-axis velocity is constant.  The y-velocity is incremented by some value every frame.  Each frame, the current x and y positions are incremented by the respective velocities.  If the card would end up below the window, y-velocity is multiplied by something like -0.9.  (negative number > -1)  This produces the series of descending bounces.

Comment: but theres some "gravity" or else it would not slow down

Comment: IIRC, the Solitaire animation displays the card in all the positions along it's path, so you'd have to modify this algorithm to remember all the places it has been and draw them appropriately.  Or just don't clear the framebuffer between frames (which I suspect is what the original solitaire did)

Comment: Gravity: The y-velocity is incremented by some value every frame.

Comment: gravity is the y-velocity being incremented each frame.  the part that makes it slow down is the -0.9 multiplier, which introduces a 10% loss in vertical velocity each time the card bounces.

Answer (score 2):

Two parts:

1. motion in the vertical direction is
   governed by a second order equation,
   like *d=1/2at²*.  For Earth, of
   course, a= 32 ft/sec² but
   you'll have to twiddle the
   constants.
2. When the card hits the edge, as
   "recursive" says, the velocity
   vector is multiplied by -1 times the
   component normal to the surface.  If
   you want it to bounce nicely to a
   stop, make the -1 some slightly
   smaller value, like -0.9.

Animate it by updating and redrawing the card some number of times a second, changing the position of the card each time. The easy way is to compute something like (pseudo-Python):

```
vel_x = # some value, units/sec
vel_y = # some value, units/sec
acc_x = # some value in units/sec^2
acc_y = # some value in units/sec^2

while not_stopped():
    x = x+vel_x
    y = y+vel_y
    # redraw the card here at new position
    if card_collided():
       # do the bounce calculation

    vel_x = x + (0.5 * acc_x)    # 1st derivative, gives units/sec
    vel_y = y + (0.5 * acc_y)
```

As long as the cards are staying four-square with the sides, then you collide with the sides when the distance between the card center and the wall is 1/2 the width or hieght as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the code Charlie provided for an hour or so, I came up with the proper algorithm (after reading recursive's response thoroughly). In real Python:

```
def bouncing_cards():
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0
    vel_x = 3.0
    vel_y = 4.0

    while x < windowWidth:
        drawImage(img, x, y)
        x += vel_x
        y += vel_y
        vel_y += 1.0
        if y + cardHeight >= windowHeight:
            y = windowHeight - cardHeight
            vel_y *= -0.9
```

Gives the following using wxPython: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJkaQ.png :)